# Boton que suma tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

*El programa tiene la funcion de que segun apretes en **"boton_sum"** o el **"boton_res"** sume o reste de a una unidad al **entry**.* Cuando intente crear la funcion que se iba a aplicar al **"boton_sum"** me di cuenta que el **text** del **label** es de tipo **str** por lo que no iba a poder sumarle un numero (lo mismo para el boton de restar). Tenia pensado que podria hacer algo con **IntVar** pero no se como hacer que se aplique a ese **text**. Otro cosa que me gustaria saber que es menos relevante es como hacer para centrar el label y los buttons de tal forma que queden en el medio del cuadro 200x200, porque como podran ver la forma en la que los centre en probable que no sea la mas optima (los centre con un pady)

```
from tkinter import *

# raiz
root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

# funciones 
def sumar():
    pass

# frame
fframe = Frame(root)
fframe.pack()

sframe = Frame(root)
sframe.pack()

# label
numero = Label(fframe, text = "0")
numero.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = (60, 0))

# Buttons
boton_sum = Button(sframe, text = "+")
boton_sum.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

boton_res = Button(sframe, text = " - ")
boton_res.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Otra Solución

( En tu código no veo ningún entry )

Para usar variables de control primero debes crearla y asignarla a una variable
`resultado = IntVar()` como es una variable `IntVar` por defecto su valor es 0, ya teniendo nuestra variable de control se la debemos asignar al `Label` mediante su atributo `textvariable`.

en el `boton_sum` tendremos que hacer uso de una función `lambda` para poder pasarle una argumento a nuestra función `sumar`.

dentro de la función `sumar` creamos una variable `suma` donde obtendremos el valor de la variable de control y a ese valor le sumaremos 1, para luego cambiar el valor de la variable de control con su método `set`.

```
resultado = IntVar()
 
def sumar(resultado):
    suma = resultado.get() + 1 # obtenemos el valor de la variable de control y le sumamos 1
    resultado.set(suma) # actualizamos la variable de control

numero = Label(fframe, textvariable=resultado)# le pasamos la variable de control

boton_sum = Button(sframe, text = "+", command=lambda: sumar(resultado))
```

## Resultado

[image]

Comment: solo me queda una duda, como hago para poner con el label de igual forma de la funcion sumar, la funcion restar, porque solo puedo poner una

Comment: al label no le tienes que cambiar nada, tienes que crear un función similar a la de suma pero para restar